# Retrieve joint locations and angles of robotic arms

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS. I wanted to ask whether with using MoveIt or any other package with a robotic arm you are able to retrieve the joint positions and angles from whatever configuration the robotic arm is in.

I plan to use ROS with a robotic arm for reinforcement learning so when an action is taken I want to know what the joint locations and angles are to begin with and what the joint locations and angles are after the action is taken.

Note: I do not want to specify what location of the joints I want the arm to move to - rather, I want to know what the location of the joints is when I apply some random action.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306517/retrieve-joint-locations-and-angles-of-robotic-arms/) by [mellow54](https://answers.ros.org/users/38170/mellow54/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In typical setups the joint states of a robot are published on a `joint_states` topic with messages of type [sensor_msgs/JointState](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html).

Those would allow you to be notified of the current pose (in joint space) of a robot, simulated or not.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mellow54](https://answers.ros.org/users/38170/mellow54/) on 2018-10-23**:
Thanks! This is what I wanted